# Call a function ogads load.php

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
$("#overlay").fadeIn("slow");
      
   
$("#verify-btn").on("click", function() {
 
  $("#locker-content").fadeOut("slow", function() {
  $("#locker-content").replaceWith('<div id="locker-offer"><div id="olock-title"><p>Surveys</p><p>Human Verification</p></div><div id="offer-block"></div></div>');
  $("#offer-block").load('load.php');
  $("#locker-content").fadeIn("slow");
  });call_locker();

 });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300,400,500,600,700,800,900');
@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    color: transparent
  }
}

.loader__dot {
  animation: 1s blink infinite
}

.loader__dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 250ms
}

.loader__dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 500ms
}

.step {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#locker-title {
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fa6400;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#complete {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.fa-lock {
  float: right;
  color: #fff!important;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#locker-content {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#verify-btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fa6400;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

#verify-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fb7d4b;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

#locker-captcha {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#locker-captcha p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

#locker-captcha i {
  color: #fa6400;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#locker-footer {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 788px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#olock-title {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

#olock-title p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

#olock-title p:first-child {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}

.offer,
.offer:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fa6400;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.offer:hover {
  background: #fa6400;
  color: #fff;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.offer:hover .badge {
  background: #fff;
  color: #fa6400;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.offer:hover .timer {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.offer:hover .timer:before {
  background: rgb(150, 42, 6);
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.offer p {
  font-size: 14px!important;
  line-height: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/bd87eb43df.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.hostedfiles.net/contentlockers/load.php?id=df6f1a66c77741994c029a4cd60742ce"></script>
>
      <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
   <div id="overlay">
  <div id="gateway">
   <div id="locker-title">HUMAN VERIFICATION REQUIRED <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 25px;"></i><span id="complete">Complete <b>2</b> of the offers to claim your resources.</span></div>
   <div id="locker-content">
   <button id="verify-btn">Verify Trough Survey </button>
   <div id="locker-captcha">
   <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
   <p>veriCAPTCHA</p>
   </div> 
   </div>
   
  </div>
  </div>
```

1. I create a script where I click the replaceWith () button when I click the button. Among other things I change the contents of another div and frame with id offer-block I would like to call_locker ()  load.php

   2. https://www.areyouahuman.co/contentlockers/load.php?id=8fafdf8fb2e51b7e6b20ea84ba1489e5
   3. after loading a frame. For this purpose I wrote such a script

   4.orginals: http://wgrajo.pl/img/22o5aj.gif

   5.script: https://codepen.io/gustawa/pen/EoRpwE

Unfortunately it does not work - what's wrong?

Comment: Is the call locker function in the file hosted on hostedfiles.net?

Comment: Yes hostedfiles.net

Comment: hi btc4cash new scrypt https://codepen.io/gustawa/pen/ypRmXg  Unfortunately it does not work - what's wrong? load.php

Answer (score 0):

The histed file your are trying to include in the page using the  have two issue.

1. It's a PHP file. If the hosted file is really a PHP file, include it in php instead using the  tag.
2. I recomend you to put all the file of your project in a clear structure of directory or even all in the same directory, this way you can  any js script or include / require php file directly.

Sample code:

```
<?php 
include "./load.php"; 
//This will include load.php which located in actual 
//directory of the current file.
?>
[...]
<html>
    <head>
    [...]
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/anyjsfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: It also does not work unless I need to get a link from the cpa ogads network.
Here is one more example of how it works :     https:// myfilescloud.pl/load.php

Comment: I'm not sure to clearly understand what you mean,but you should do what Ive told you. Host yourself the whole website project files.

Comment: thanks to advise you I got the entire .php file from the ogads slide

Comment: If that worked please mark my answer as the correct one:)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

//setup required variables
$userid = "MYUSERID"; //<< fill this in with your userid
$country = "US";
$device = "android";

//url to request
$url = "https://mobverify.com/api/v1/?affiliateid=".urlencode($userid)."&country=".urlencode($country)."&device=".urlencode($device);

//initialize curl
$ch = curl_init();

//setup curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//make request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if($response === false) {
 //curl error occurred, handle it how you like
 echo curl_error($ch);
}

//close the curl object
curl_close($ch);

if($response !== false) {
 //curl request was successful

 //decode the json response into a php array
 $json = json_decode($response, true);

 if($json === false) {
  //failed to decode json response
  echo json_last_error_msg();

 } elseif($json['success']) {
  //api call was successful

  //loop through the offers
  foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {

   //as an example we output the offer names
   echo "<p>".$offer['name']."</p>";
  }

 } else {
  //api error occurred, handle it how you like
  echo $json['error'];
 }

}

?>
```

it works. but thank you for help.